# How to Convert cursor.fetchall() to python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to Convert SQL query output to python DataFrame with the column name.

I did Something like this but it's not giving column as well as not a proper DataFrame.

```py
result_set=cursor.fetchall()
df=pd.DataFrame(result_set)
```

Comment: I think [pandas.read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: I need to pass multiple parameters while executing procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Hi I think what you looking for is this. you need to add column header before you put in to Data Frame

```
cursor.execute("your SQL Statement")

column_Names  = cursor.description
        
result = [{columns[index][0]: column for index, column in enumerate(value)} for value in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: change the columns[index][0] to column_Names[index][0]